# Is it possible to send email on behalf of others using SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am creating a SaaS application that uses SES to send emails.  The system sends emails to customers of my users.  I would like these emails to come from my users' domain, rather than my own.

My understanding of SES is that you need to manually verify the domain before you can send email from it.  This makes sense, but for my use case it isn't viable.

I thought that having my users add an SPF record to their DNS for my app's hostname would be enough, but from reading the docs I would need to manually verify the domain before I can send via SES too.

Is it possible to send emails on behalf of my users in SES?

Answer (score 0):

Verifying a domain is as simple as putting the `TXT` record that SES provides into your domain's DNS settings. There is no further step required for domain verification.

The TXT record is of the form `_amazonses.<<YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>>`

You can additionally add DKIM settings but that is all optional